# Angular: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'found')

Tags: angular

I want to custom validators in angular, so that after I submited form and call API, the variable notExisted set to true and throw out error message.
Here is my code :

```
public 
  public notExisted = true;
  get f() {
    return this.forgotPasswordForm.controls;
  }
//API 
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.forgotPasswordForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this._authenticationService.forgotPassword(this.f.email.value)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data.statusCode)
          if (data.statusCode == 200 || data.statusCode == '200') {
            this.notExisted = false;
            this.sended = true;
          } else if (data.statusCode == 204 || data.statusCode == '204') {
            this.notExisted = true;
            this.sended = false;
            this.error = data.content;;
          } else {
            this.notExisted = false;
            this.sended = false
            this.error = data.content;
          }
        }
  }
//custom validator
existValidator(control: FormControl) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.notExisted !== undefined) {
        if (this.notExisted == true) {
          resolve({ notExisted: true });
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }

    });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log(this.currentDate);

    this.forgotPasswordForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email,this.existValidator]]
    });

    // Subscribe to config changes
    this._coreConfigService.config.pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll)).subscribe(config => {
      this.coreConfig = config;
    });
  }
```

and here is my HTML

```
<form class="auth-forgot-password-form mt-2" [formGroup]="forgotPasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="form-label" for="forgot-password-email">Email</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="john@example.com"
                aria-describedby="forgot-password-email" autofocus="" tabindex="1"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors}" />
              <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
                <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.notExisted"Not found</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" tabindex="2" rippleEffect>Send reset link</button>
          </form>
```

But after i submit, the console throw exception like this

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'found')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'found')
at src_app_main_pages_pages_module_ts.js:906:27
at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills.js:10389:21)
at push.9650.AuthForgotPasswordV2Component.existValidator (src_app_main_pages_pages_module_ts.js:904:16)
at vendor.js:76993:12
at Array.map (\<anonymous\>)
at executeValidators (vendor.js:76992:21)
at FormControl.\_composedValidatorFn (vendor.js:77023:24)
at FormControl.\_runValidator (vendor.js:78668:36)
at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (vendor.js:78631:28)
at FormControl.setValue (vendor.js:79115:12)
at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:10309:19)
at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills.js:10391:9)
at push.9650.AuthForgotPasswordV2Component.existValidator (src_app_main_pages_pages_module_ts.js:904:16)
at vendor.js:76993:12
at Array.map (\<anonymous\>)
at executeValidators (vendor.js:76992:21)
at FormControl.\_composedValidatorFn (vendor.js:77023:24)
at FormControl.\_runValidator (vendor.js:78668:36)
at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (vendor.js:78631:28)
at FormControl.setValue (vendor.js:79115:12)
```

how to fix this ?

i want that after i submit, it show error message not found

Comment: I think you should turn into development mode so you get better error stack. In any case, I see no code trying to read the property 'found' so I think the error is coming from other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The validator you are using is having asynchronous code, due to the use of promise, so they need to be added separately in the async validator array. Which is the third argument, please check the below example!

Since you are using `this` operator please bind the method to the scope of the component during execution using `.bind(this)`

```
this.forgotPasswordForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], [this.existValidator.bind(this)]] // second array is the async validator array!
});
```

Comment: your answer actuall solve this but after i call API the variable notExist doesn't change and i can't call my API again. Do you know what is the problem